# Getting initialized error and can't figure out how to fix my array list

Tags: java, string, arraylist, initialization, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a calculator and I got the operations right but I keep getting a "variable may not have been initialized" error, I want it to print that if the user inputs "a" then it will say "addition", "s" is "subtraction" and so on, but it keeps displaying as zero.
Also, my array list repeats like 5 times in rows instead of making one columned list. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
   String selection;

   List<String> operation = new ArrayList<String>(); 
  
   operation.add("(A)dd");
   operation.add("(S)ubtract");
   operation.add("(M)ultiply");
   operation.add("(D)ivide");
   operation.add("(E)xit");
   
   System.out.println(operation);
   
   String letter = scanner.nextLine();
   {
   System.out.println("Operation? " + letter);
   System.out.println("You selected " + selection);
   //chosing the operation
   if("a".equals(letter))
   {
      selection = "addition';
   }
   System.out.println("You selected " + selection);
```

Answer (score 0):

You created `String selection`, you didn't give it a value. A variable inside a method has to be assigned a value before it is used.

So, declare it outside or assign a value before using it in `System.out.println("You selected " + selection);`

Answer (score 0):

initialize selection
ex:String selection =" ";